Common values for GPX <type> field?
The GPX schema defines an optional <type> field which can be applied to waypoints, tracks or routes.  The schema says the field describes the "Type (classification)" of the element, but doesn't give any further details.
Are there any well-known values for the <type> field?
I presume that the field is used to describe the type of activity that generated the track/waypoint, e.g. cycling. I'd like to do this in a way that is, if possible, common with other software, so I'm looking for any standard which would tell me whether to use "Biking" as opposed to "Cycling" or "Bike ride", for instance.
